# Prevent a cookie from expiring when the browser is closed?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, chromium

How do I prevent cookies from expiring when my browser is closed?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Those cookies are set that way for security. If you are asking about how to set a cookie's expiration date on your own site, then see these [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp) methods.

Comment: By "you can't" do you really mean "you shouldn't"? Or do you mean "it's impossible"?

Comment: I mean that some sites employ not only timeouts for validating cookies, but a hashed value that also has a server-side timeout value that will no longer authenticate no matter what the local timeout value is.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [cookie editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg)?

Comment: Awww... it doesn't seem to work with my version of Chromium. :( But +1 thanks anyway, I'll give it a try later if I can.

Comment: While the above link still works more than ten years later it looks as if EditThisCookie has had a [rather bad track record](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-editthiscookie-chrome-extension/) so maybe use [Cookie-Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-editor/hlkenndednhfkekhgcdicdfddnkalmdm) instead.

Comment: If you are running Chrome you might not need an extension in the first place, because – at least nowadays – it has an integrated cookie editor in [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/application/cookies/) which works quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Cookies pane](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/application/cookies/) to change the [`Expire`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) attribute from `Session` to some arbitrary date in the future. That effectively converts the session cookies to persistent cookies.

You mileage may vary though because as correctly [mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/334211/prevent-a-cookie-from-expiring-when-the-browser-is-closed#comment366537_334213) the server-side timeout is authorative.

It seems though as there may be cases where the server-side session timeout is actually longer than the `Expires` attribute of the corresponding cookie.

I just had a case where a website foobar using authentication via a single sign-on service required a re-login as soon as the last browser window of the website was closed. Adding an `Expires` attribute to the session cookie kept the session alive even after restarting the browser.

Alternatively adding an `Expires` attribute to the authentication cookie of the single sign-on service requires a re-login on the website foobar but avoids having to re-enter the credentials at the single sign-on service.

Manually editing cookie attributes is obviously not very user-friendly, so wrapping the procedure into some browser extension or userscript seems meaningful.